# Setting up inotify (incron) to monitor several directories using asterisk

Tags: linux, cron, inotify, incrond, incrontab

I am trying to create an entry in `/etc/incron.d/` that'd monitor all changes done under the following directories:

```
/var/www/virtualhosts/dev.anuary.com/*/*/public/css
```

Now, I assume this should be as simple as:

```
/var/www/virtualhosts/dev.anuary.com/*/*/public/css IN_MODIFY,IN_NO_LOOP php /var/www/virtualhosts/dev.anuary.com/test.php $@/$#
```

However, the latter doesn't work. I cannot list every directory simply because they change quite irregularly.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think this is possible.
The path must be a absolute path.

There is also [Watcher](https://github.com/greggoryhz/Watcher), I'm unsure if it supports wild-cards in the path, from what I understand of it's documentation, it doesn't.

But you could use it to recursively monitor `/var/www/virtualhosts/dev.anuary.com/` and adapt the command you are running to do nothing with files that aren't in `/var/www/virtualhosts/dev.anuary.com/*/*/public/css`